# javascript - convert an array of strings and numbers to an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, double-quotes

I have an array of strings and numbers. I need to convert all items to numbers, i.e :

```
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10];
```

convert to:

```
[42.00, 33, 12.02, 30, 10]
```

Comment: var b=parseInt(a[0]);

Comment: "I have an array of number" - No you don't ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fallback compatibily purpose:

```
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10];
var out;

if (typeof(Array.prototype.map == 'function')) {
    out = a.map(function(el){ return typeof(el) !== 'number' ? parseFloat(el) : el });
}
else {
    out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        out[i] = typeof(a[i]) !== 'number' ? parseFloat(a[i]) : a[i];   
    }
}

console.log(out);
```

if the element is already a number it won't parse it, else it will.

if the .map function is not defined, it will procede using a regular for loop. This should be done because some browsers does not support some ECMA functions (like IE9):

[image]

fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/kndgcty8/1/

Comment: I got the .map function is not defined error, but it didn't do the else, so I put only your else block, change typeof(el) to typeof(a[i]) (probably a mistake of you because copy/past ^^) now it works perfectly,   thanks :)

Comment: @Luckyn: Yes, I've edited the post about 1 min after posting, changing el to a[i] :p

Comment: And i see that you also fix the if problem ^^ all the code works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10];
var b=new Array();

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  b[i]=parseFloat(a[i]);

alert(a);
alert(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Array `map` method:

```
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10]
var b = a.map(function (elem) {
    return parseInt(elem, 10)
})
console.log(b)
// [42, 33, 12, 30, 10]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/o8dnf80o/1/)

Comment: Worth noting that this will only work in IE9 or later (if you are using IE of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10];
var b = [];
a.forEach(function(num){
    b.push(parseFloat(num));
});
console.log(b);
// [42, 33, 12, 30, 10]
```

Or add prototype method to Array:

```
Array.prototype.toInt = function (a){
    var b = [];
    this.forEach(function(num){
        b.push(parseFloat(num));
    });
    return b;
}
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10];
console.log(a.toInt());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0okLL93m/

I'm sure this could be written better somehow, but works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Really, what's up with writing a full paragraph of code for something this simple? This is all you need:

```
var a = ["42.00", 33, 12.02, "30", 10]

a.map(Number) // returns [42, 33, 12.02, 30, 10]
```

(note that all numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating-point, no point writing them explicitly as float)